# how to use angular-cli options after create project

Tags: angular, terminal, routes, angular-cli, angular5

I use this command for create `myProject` :

```
ng new myProject
```

Instead of :

```
ng new myProject --routing
```

So , I dont have `app-routing.modules.ts` file in `myProject/src/app/`

How can I alter `myProject` with angular-cli,to add some options that I forget them?

Comment: as for --routing, you'd have to add a Routing module manually (which is easy). For some other options, you can edit your .angular-cli.json

Comment: Read, learn, use: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to generate routing module

> ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app